# failed to integrate facebook connect to native android app Failed to find provider info

Tags: android, facebook, connection, hashmap, provider

I want to integrate facebook connection into my native android app
to do that, I have followed the tuto of facebook doc
but always I have thefollowing error :

```
12-24 10:03:28.359: E/ActivityThread(3569): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
12-24 10:05:37.119: D/dalvikvm(4104): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F
```

firsly, the popup of connexion is displayed but after logging I they don't arrive to run this code :

```
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
  public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (session.isOpened()) {

      // make request to the /me API
      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

        // callback after Graph API response with user object
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
          if (user != null) {
            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

I don't know the cause
I have generate the hashkey and create the app but always thjis error

in the first time I had the error which said that I don't have the same version of android-support-v4, to fix that, I have removed my app's one and let it work with the library-s one

my facebook account is verified

I have seen the other posts but I don't find the solution

how can I fix this issue

thank you

Comment: any solution to it ? i m also facing the same prblm !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, the problem was from the hash key, you have to read the has key like that :

```
        // Add code to print out the key hash
            try {
                PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                        "com.example.testhopelast",
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                            Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

            }
```

and set this hach key in the facebook dashboard, surely, the one which you have set is not correct due to the version of openssl or something else